Navigate to previous/ next window using shortcut
I am looking for a way to focus/ switch to the previous or next window using shortcuts (ideally something like Super+Left and Super+Right). I am aware of Alt+Tab, but this is not what I am looking for, as it just cycles through the windows. Is this possible in Ubuntu 22?

Pls read this, https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask it is one of the help links that are available in Help at the bottom of the page, and as to your question, yes you can create keybord shortcuts, as to how I refer you to the link.

By default, Alt+Esc is assigned to "switch windows directly". Holding Alt and then hitting Esc will cycle through the windows. Holding and releasing the key combination will switch between the current window and the previous.
